# c# Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure

Tags: c#

I have this method to run cmd command on remote workstation. I need to use namespace Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure instead of System.management. How can I do?

```
public static void RemoteExecute(string cmd, string wks){
 var processToRun = new[] { cmd };
 var wmiScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\cimv2", wks));
 var wmiProcess = new ManagementClass(wmiScope, new ManagementPath("Win32_Process"), new ObjectGetOptions());
 wmiProcess.InvokeMethod("Create", processToRun);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to go to Package Manager and install  Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.

Next if you have a using statement for System.Management, remove it

Finally add a using Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure statement

Comment: I have already done what you indicated. The problem is ManagementScope and ManagementClass class use System.Management. How can I "convert" the code to use Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure?